# How do I convert a string to lower within an if statement c++

Tags: c++

Something like this:

```
if (string.toLower() == "string") {
    cout << "output";
}
```

I have tried using:  `transform(input.begin(), input.end(), input.begin(), toupper);`
with no results.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Interesting logic you have there.. You want to invoke `tolower` for every element in the string, so, you try invoking `std::transform`, with `toupper`, and are surprised that it didn't "lower" the characters..

Answer (score 3):

Indeed you can use [`std::tolower()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/tolower) with [`std::transform()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) to achieve this. For example:

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>

std::string to_lower(const std::string& s) {
    std::string lower{s};
    std::transform(lower.begin(), lower.end(), lower.begin(), 
                   [](unsigned char c){ return std::tolower(c); });
    return lower;
}

int main()
{
    std::string str{"UPPER_CASE"};

    if (to_lower(str) == "upper_case")
        std::cout << "String matched.";

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```xml
String matched.
```

[Note here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/tolower#Parameters) that for `std::tolower(int ch)`: *"If the value of `ch` is not representable as `unsigned char` and does not equal `EOF`, the behavior is undefined"*. Hence the *lambda* taking an `unsigned char` as the 4th argument to `std::transform`.

Also note that [upon NRVO for calls](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) to `to_lower()`, should such optimization takes place, no extra `std::string` is being copied -- beyond once for the single one necessary to hold the lower case version.

Comment: You don't even need lambda expression. `std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin(), std::tolower);` works just as well, and is shorter.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius [Note here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/tolower#Notes): "*the argument should first be converted to `unsigned char`*".

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius `std::tolower` has an overload declared in `<clocale>` - if that header is included, this won't compile. Alternative to lambda would be writing `static_cast<int(*)(int)>(&std::tolower)`, to allow for correct overload resolution.

Comment: Interesting, I never noticed such a note, nor noticed any unexpected behavior without the cast before (probably due to me using mostly strings based in English language). But, now it makes sense, due to integer promotion rules, the resulting value of `int` might be different depending if original char value is negative, and wasn't converted to `unsigned char` prior to conversion to `int`, as opposed to where it was. Thanks for pointing that out to me :)

Answer (score 1):

Using C++17 [`if` with initializer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::string value {"Hello World"};

    if (
        std::string lower{value}, dummy{lower.end(), std::transform(
            lower.begin(), lower.end(), lower.begin(),
            [](unsigned char c){ return std::tolower(c); }
        )};
        !lower.compare("hello world")
    ) {
        std::cout << "equal" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are causing *undefined behavior* for not casting `std::string` elements to `unsigned char` -- see documentation of `std::tolower()`.

Answer (score -1):

what about something like this :

```
string LowerCaseString(string  str) {
  string ret;
  for (auto chr : str) {
      ret += tolower(chr);
  }
  return ret;
}

if (LowerCaseString(somestring) == "string") {
     // do something
}
```